# Looping through an object converted to array, and its properties' names. How to do it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to loop through an object using Object.keys, and by validating its properties' names.

EDIT: I've cleaned up a bit of my code, according to some suggestions given in the comment section (thank you so much!):

```
const checkForEmptyFields = array => {
    let emptyField = false;
    const voidArray = array === null || array === undefined;

    if (!voidArray) {
        for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            const keys = Object.keys(array[i]);

            for (let key = 0; key < keys.length; key++) {
                const irrelevantProperties =
                    keys[key].toLowerCase() === 'observations' ||
                    keys[key].toLowerCase() === 'flag' ||
                    keys[key].toLowerCase() === 'id';

                if (!irrelevantProperties)
                    if (array[i][keys[key]].toString().length === 0) {
                        emptyField = true;
                        break;
                    }
            }
            if (emptyField) break;
        }
    }
    return emptyField;
};
```

Somehow the loop catches an undefined value in the array (object converted). What am I missing?

[Previous shameful mistakey code]

```
const checkForEmptyFields = array => {
    if (array !== null || array !== undefined) {
        for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            const keys = Object.keys(array[i]);

            keys.forEach((key, index) => {
                if (
                    key.toLowerCase() !== 'observations' ||
                    key.toLowerCase() !== 'flag' ||
                    key.toLowerCase() !== 'id'
                )
                    if (array[i].key.toString().length === 0) {
                        return true;
                    }
            });
        }
    }
    return false;
};
```

Comment: What kind of elements are in the array? Is it only objects?

Comment: `array !== null || array !== undefined` will always be true; if the first condition is false, then the second must be true and vice versa, since `array` can't equal `null` and `undefined` at the same time. Same for the other `if`. Which is probably your problem…?

Comment: You probably want `array[i][key]`, not `.key`.

Comment: LIkewise the `if` statement starting  `if ( key.toLowerCase()  ...` always succeeds - `key` will always be not equal to one of the values tested. See [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) about boolean logic.

Comment: @НикитаНигматуллин, yes, all elements are always expected to be objects!

Answer (score 0):

Try skipping entries in the array that are not actually objects:

```
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if( array[i] === null || typeof array[i] != "object") {
        continue;
    }
    const keys = Object.keys(array[i]);
    // ... more code
```

You mentioned in comments that array entries are objects, so skipping numbers, strings and other data types in addition to skipping `undefined` shouldn't be a problem.